# Formulário funciona em desktop mais no responsivo não!

Tags: php, javascript, html5, formulário, envio-de-email

Estou com um problema que é o seguinte tenho uma pagina page.php, que tem alguns includes php puxando arquivos que contém a estrutura do meu formulário, que depois envia para uma pagina com mensagem de "sucesso", no desktop ele funciona perfeitamente, porém no responsivo simplesmente não acontece nada, se eu deixo os campos vazios ele me retorna erro por esta vazio mais quando esta preenchido certo nada acontece, já tentei validar os campos em html 5 usando o required, como achei que fosse esse o problema apaguei e tentei em js, porém nada ainda... Segue o código que estou tentando:

```
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f728-p242-o1" lang="pt-BR" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="http://www.site.com.br/seguro-guincho-24-horas-recebido-com-sucesso" id="formulario" onsubmit="return calculo();" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
<h2>Dados do Cliente</h2>
<p>Seu nome (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name">
    <input type="text" name="nome" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Data de Nascimento<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-nascimento">
    <input type="text" name="nascimento" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" />
  </span></p>
<p>Seu CPF ou CNPJ (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-cpf">
    <input type="text" name="cpf" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Seu Endereço com número (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-end">
    <input type="text" name="endereco" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Complemento<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-comp">
    <input type="text" name="complemento" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" />
  </span></p>
<p>Seu Bairro (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-bairro">
    <input type="text" name="bairro" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Sua Cidade (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-cidade">
    <input type="text" name="cidade" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Seu Estado (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-estado">
    <input type="text" name="estado" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Seu Cep (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-cep">
    <input type="text" name="cep" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Seu Telefone (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-tel">
    <input type="text" name="telefone" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Telefone 2<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-tel2">
    <input type="text" name="telefone2" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" aria-invalid="false" />
  </span></p>
<p>Seu e-mail (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email">
    <input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Como nos conheceu<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-868">
    <select name="outros" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" aria-invalid="false">
      <option value="Outros">Outros</option>
      <option value="Indicação de Amigo">Indicação de Amigo</option>
      <option value="Google">Google</option>
      <option value="Yahoo">Yahoo</option>
      <option value="MSN">MSN</option>
      <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
      <option value="Skype">Skype</option>
      <option value="Renovação">Renovação</option>
    </select>
  </span></p>
<p>Obs:<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message">
    <textarea name="mensagem" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea"></textarea>
  </span></p>
<h2>Dados do Veículo</h2>
<p>Marca (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap marca">
    <input type="text" name="marca" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Modelo (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap modelo">
    <input type="text" name="modelo" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Ano de Fabricação / Ano do modelo (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap ano">
    <input type="text" name="ano" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Cor (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap cor">
    <input type="text" name="cor" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Placa (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap placa">
    <input type="text" name="placa" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Chassi (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap chassi">
    <input type="text" name="chassi" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  </span></p>
<p>Combustível (obrigatório)<br />
  <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap menu-372">
    <select name="combustivel" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select">
      <option value="Total Flex">Total Flex</option>
      <option value="Gasolina">Gasolina</option>
      <option value="Álcool">Álcool</option>
      <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
      <option value="Bio Diesel">Bio Diesel</option>
      <option value="GNV">GNV</option>
      <option value="Elétrico">Elétrico</option>
    </select>
  </span></p>
<h2>Aceite de Contrato</h2>
<p><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap contrato"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox wpcf7-validates-as-required"><span class="wpcf7-list-item first last">
  <input type="checkbox" name="contrato" value="Li as Condições Gerais da Assistência 24 horas para Guinchos e Aceito" <?php /*?>required<?php */?> />
  <span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">Li as Condições Gerais da Assistência 24 horas para Guinchos e Aceito</span></span></span></span><br />
  <a href="<?php echo site_url(''); ?>/plano-de-seguro-guincho-24-horas-pdf" target="_blank">Clique Aqui para ler as condições.</a> (Obrigatório)</p>
<p>
<input type="hidden" value="comercial@site.com.br" name="emaildestinatario" />
<input type="hidden" value="Formulário do Site - Guinchos" name="assunto" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="campo-cinza" value="Contrate Com PagSeguro" tabindex="13"/>
</p>
</form>
</div>


<script>
function validaErroBranco(campo, mensagem) {
    if (campo.value !== "") return true;
    alert(mensagem);
    campo.focus();
    return false;
}

function calculo() {
    var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");

    var valido = validaErroBranco(formulario.nome, "Preencha seu nome corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.email, "Preencha seu e-mail corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.telefone, "Preencha seu telefone corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.endereco, "Preencha seu endereço corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.cidade, "Preencha sua cidade corretamente.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.cpf, "Preencha o campo CPF.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.bairro, "Preencha o campo Bairro*.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.estado, "Preencha o campo Estado.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.cep, "Preencha o campo CEP.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.marca, "Preencha o campo Marca.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.modelo, "Preencha o campo Modelo.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.ano, "Preencha o campo Ano.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.cor, "Preencha o campo Cor.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.placa, "Preencha o campo Placa.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.chassi, "Preencha o campo Chassi.")
        && validaErroBranco(formulario.contrato, "Preencha o campo Contrato.");
if (!valido) return false;
            }       
</script>
```

Comment: Sua função `calculo` só possui um `return false`, mas não retorna quando é verdadeiro. Já tentou colocar apenas `return valido`?

Comment: Então ficaria dessa forma?

Comment: if (!valido){
  return false;
}else{
return true;
   }
}

Comment: Que é a mesma coisa que `return valido;`, então o `if` é desnecessário.

Comment: Vou estar aqui dessa forma

Comment: Ainda nada, clico no botão de envio e simplesmente não ocorre nada.

Comment: Tentei para de usar a forma nativa do Wp para verificar url para testar, porém ainda nada de resultado: <?php $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
<?php if ( $url == "/contrate-assistencia-auto-24-horas/" ) { ?>